Creating a 'Draw Line' Button with Mouse Clicks in PyQt5
I'm using PyQt5 to build a GUI program similar to Microsoft Paint, but specifically for drawing shapes (components) and lines (wires) on an adjustable circuit board. So far, I've created the circuit board and can draw shapes that can be moved with the mouse. In a separate Python file, I've also written code to draw lines using mouse clicks. The code is as follows:
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor, QPen
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt,QPoint

class DrawingWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.destination = QPoint()
        self.setWindowTitle("Drawing Example")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        self.line1x = []
        self.line1y = []
        self.line2y = []
        self.line2x = []

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = event.pos()
            self.destination = self.begin
            self.line1x.append(event.x())
            self.line1y.append(event.y())
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.destination = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2)
        painter.setPen(pen)

        if self.line2x:
            range_limit = len(self.line2x)
            for i in range(0,range_limit):
                painter.drawLine(self.line1x[i],self.line1y[i],self.line2x[i],self.line2y[i])
        painter.drawLine(self.begin, self.destination)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = QPoint()
            self.destination = QPoint()
            self.line2x.append(event.x())
            self.line2y.append(event.y())
            self.update()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DrawingWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

The issue is that this isn't a single function but rather a set of functions within a class, which has made it challenging to integrate into my main program and call it with a button. Below is my main code, which includes the line-drawing class (some parts are omitted):
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QMessageBox,
    QApplication,
    QMainWindow, QLineEdit,
    QLabel, QPushButton,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QGraphicsView,
    QGraphicsScene,
    QGraphicsItem,
    QWidget
)
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import (
    QIntValidator,
    QDoubleValidator,
    QFont,
    QBrush,
    QPen,
    QPainter,
    QColor
)
import sys
import string

class LineDraw_class(QGraphicsItem):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.begin = QPoint()
        self.destination = QPoint()
        self.line1x = []
        self.line1y = []
        self.line2y = []
        self.line2x = []


    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = event.pos()
            self.destination = self.begin
            # self.line1 = (event.x(),event.y())
            self.line1x.append(event.x())
            self.line1y.append(event.y())
            self.update()
            print("mousepress")

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.destination = event.pos()
            self.update()
            print("mousemove")

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pen = QPen(Qt.black, 2)
        painter.setPen(pen)
        print("mousemoveevent")
        if self.line2x:
            range_limit = len(self.line2x)
            for i in range(0,range_limit):
                painter.drawLine(self.line1x[i],self.line1y[i],self.line2x[i],self.line2y[i])
        painter.drawLine(self.begin, self.destination)

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() & Qt.LeftButton:
            self.begin = QPoint()
            self.destination = QPoint()
            self.line2x.append(event.x())
            self.line2y.append(event.y())
            print("mouserelease")
            self.update()

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Boardas")
        self.setGeometry(300,200,1040,640)
        self.create_ui()
        self.show()
    def make_square(self):
        rect = scene.addRect(17, 10, 50, 50, blackPen)
        rect.setFlag(QGraphicsItem.ItemIsMovable)
    def draw_new_line(self):
        drawn_line = LineDraw_class()

#functions for some buttons are skipped
        
    def create_ui(self):
        global scene
        scene = QGraphicsScene(self)

        global blackPen
        blackPen = QPen(Qt.black)
        blackPen.setWidth(4)

        self.view = QGraphicsView(scene, self)
        self.view.setGeometry(0, 0, 740, 640)

#the for loop below generates a set of ellipses that form a circuit board
        j = 0
        z = 0
        x = 23
        y = 8

        x_values = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M',
               'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']

        y_values = ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10',
                   '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
                   '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
                   '31', '32']

        for i in range (x*y):

            if j == 0:
                x_1 = x
                for x_1 in range(x_1):
                    w = scene.addText(x_values[x_1])
                    w.moveBy(7+x_1*17, 0)
            if z % x == 0:
                j = j+1
                z = 0
            y_1 = y
            c = 0
            for c in reversed(range(y_1)):
                index = y_1 - c -1
                w = scene.addText(y_values[index])
                w.moveBy(-15, c*17+19)

            ellipse = scene.addEllipse(10+z*17,10+j*17,10,10, blackPen)
            z = z + 1



        self.b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b3.setText("Make a square")
        self.b3.move(770, 80)
        self.b3.clicked.connect(self.make_square)
        self.b3.adjustSize()

#buttons b4~b7 are skipped

        self.b8 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.b8.setText("Draw a line")
        self.b8.move(840, 340)
        self.b8.clicked.connect(self.draw_new_line)
        self.b8.adjustSize()



app = QApplication([])
window = Window()
window.show()
app.exec_()

Obviously, pressing the button "Draw a line" doesn't do anything because nothing is actually in the draw_new_line(self) function. I just don't know how to make the lines appear on the screen. I've tried making drawn_line an item and messing around with the scene but it ends up crashing the program. I also don't know how to handle the paintEvent(self, event) function which has to continue to run the loop so that I still see all of the lines which I drew even if I start pressing other buttons. What might be the primary issue here? Am I missing something or misunderstanding how PyQt and its widgets work?
I realize my code might be messy and inefficient, but I’m not looking for advice on improving its structure right now. I just need help fixing the issue with the class and the button so I can move forward. Any hints would be appreciated.

First of all, graphics items are not widgets, and while they may have similar functions to override, they are not the same. Specifically, subclassing QGraphicsItem requires implementing paint() (not paintEvent()) and boundingRect(), but before trying to subclass from scratch, you should consider using existing shape-based item types, such as QGraphicsLineItem or QGraphicsPathItem. In a case like this, you probably want to "enter" a specific drawing mode (using checkable buttons), and implement mouse events on the view (either by subclassing or using an event filter) so that they »

» eventually add/edit items based on the current drawing mode: for instance, if the current mode is "line", pressing the mouse button will add a temporary QGraphicsLineItem at the scene mouse position, edit the line's target position on movement, and finalize it on release. For this, you generally don't need graphics item subclassing at all, but you should still use the proper functions (eg: setLine() for the line item that is currently being added).

Unrelated: 1. avoid using globals; 2. always use layout managers instead of fixed geometries; 3. the main contents of a QMainWindow should always be within its central widget, as creating direct children to it is generally discouraged unless you really know what you're doing: either set the view as such (and add a QToolBar with proper actions) or create a container QWidget with a proper layout and add all widgets to it.
